# Xcode Swift pass func to GameOverScene

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, scene

I need some help with my Highscore. In my GameScene.swift I set the Highscore functions but the problem is that i would like to show the Highscore in my GameOverScene.swift. Here is what I created in the GameScene.swift:

```
func operateOnScore(score:NSInteger) {
    if getBestScore() < GameScene.score {
        setBestScore(GameScene.score)
    }
}

func setBestScore(score:NSInteger){

    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    userDefaults.setObject(score, forKey: "bestscore")

    userDefaults.synchronize()
}

func getBestScore() -> NSInteger {
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    return userDefaults.objectForKey("bestscore")!.integerValue
    }
```

This works pretty well if i show it in the GameScene.swift but now I'd like to show my Highscore in my GameOverScene.swift.
I found something on Apple's development homepage but it don't work. I also set this struct to my GameScene.swift:

```
struct HS {
func  Showbest() {

    let bestFinalText = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "04b_19")
    bestFinalText.fontSize = 20
    bestFinalText.zPosition = 120
    bestFinalText.fontColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    bestFinalText.position = CGPointMake( CGRectGetMidX( self.frame )+90,CGRectGetMidY( self.frame )-10)
    bestFinalText.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.Right
    bestFinalText.text = NSString(format: "%d", self.getBestScore()) as String
    self.addChild(bestFinalText)
}

}
```

Have somebody an idea how I can pass my function to my GameOverScene?

Comment: so badically you want to share data between two swift files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to make a struct, simply you could create a new file called for example "Utils.swift" without class declaration :

Utils.swift (as you can see there isn't class declaration):

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

func getBestScore() -> NSInteger {
   let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
   return userDefaults.objectForKey("bestscore")!.integerValue
}

func showBest()->SKLabelNode {
    let bestFinalText = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "04b_19")
    bestFinalText.fontSize = 20
    bestFinalText.zPosition = 120
    bestFinalText.fontColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    bestFinalText.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.Right
    return bestFinalText
}
```

In Swift there is no need to import classes, so simply when you are in your `GameOverScene.swift` call these functions like this for example:

```
let scoreLabel = showBest()
scoreLabel.text = "points are: \(getBestScore())"
scoreLabel.position = CGPointMake( CGRectGetMidX( self.frame )+90,CGRectGetMidY( self.frame )-10)
self.addChild(scoreLabel)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this informations and your help. At the moment I always get an Thread 1 error (exc_bad_instruction). What do this error mean?

Comment: Happened when some SKNode or it's derivated (SKShapeNode, SKSpriteNode..) is nil

Comment: Now I don't get any errors but my Highscore is always 0.

Comment: Are you sure do you update everytime the new score to the NSUserDefaults?

Comment: Now it works fine. Thank you very much for your help!